# Set htmlFor property for a label tag in mootools or javascript

Tags: javascript, dom, mootools

I want to make a new label in mootools 1.3 by this command:

```
new Element('lable', {
    'for':'chk_id',
    'html':'hello'
  }).inject(document.body);
```

the label will creates with 'hello' text but 'for' property dose not apply to the label.
I test 'htmlFor' property, i can see this property in firebug but it does not work (I want to check an input with id='chk_id').
Is there any solution in mootools or javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps using `label` rather than the french-sounding `lable` may be a good place to start. 
Just make sure the for property matches the id of the input element.

`new Element("label[for=bar][text=bar]").inject(document.body);`

is fine in 1.3 :) http://jsfiddle.net/Fw9hh/

Comment: that's ok, not the first time i see this particular typo either!